# Windows phone 8 and Surface pro 2 OpenStreamForWriteAsync blocks the app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8, filestream

I'm working on a project for windows phone and surface pro 2 app and I'm looking for reading a text from a .txt file.

I'm new in windows app development and I take over the project of an other guy.

I didn't change his code for the moment but there are some things I don't understand and the main problem is that when I use the app, this one is blocked when I call the method  **OpenStreamForWriteAsync()**.

Here is the code:

```
public async void FillIn()
{
    Stream stream1 = null;
    StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary; // Gets Documents library
    //The following structure code in comment is from me, is it necessary to 
    //do all these verification or "StorageFolder storageFolder =
    //KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;" is enough ?  
    //try
    //{
    //    folder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFolderAsync(AppFolderName);
    //}
    //catch (Exception)
    //{
    //    // Folder does not exist, but we cannot await in a catch block, so we can not create it here.
    //}

    //if (folder == null)
    //{
    //    folder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFolderAsync(AppFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    //}

    // Test if the file exist
    StorageFile report1 = null;
    try
    {
        report1 = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("report_final.txt"); // Take the .txt file.
    }
    catch { }

    if (report1 == null)
    {
        // Could not find file
    }

    // PROBLEM IS HERE
    stream1 = await report1.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(); // the app is blocked at this line

    using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(stream1))
    {
        Texte = sr1.ReadToEnd();
        sr1.Dispose(); // the guy before me use this but when we use "using" 
        //isn't it suppose to call "Dispose" at the end automatically ??
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help and feel free to ask me more information if you don't understand something.

Comment: The await keyword blocks until the async call finishes. How long is it blocking for?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by blocked? Also, post the code that shows you how you invoke the FillIn method.

Comment: @MillieSmith it blocks more than 2 minutes. This time is really big because my application is a really simple program and the file used ( a .txt file) doesn't exceed 4 kb...

Comment: @LukkhaCoder When I say "blocked" I mean the app is stucked here, nothing happen. I used the debugger to go step by step and I can't go to the next line.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder 
The code that shows how I invoke the FillIn method is the follozing code :

`private void Send(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e){
FillIn();
SendPost();
SendRequest(url,Texte);
SendButton.IsEnabled = false;
Application.Current.Exit();            
}`
Sorry for the ugly presentation I don't know how to get a code balise in the comment.

Comment: Well you're running on the main thread, but you're right... it still should be really quick. Have you tried a different file?

Comment: @MillieSmith In fact every time I run the app I create a different file stored in local, so yes I tried different file. I work on Microsoft Surface pro 2, maybe it will help...

Comment: @ChrisNilson When it finally returns, are you getting an access denied or anything? And do you need to use async calls when you're blocking anyway? Tried running a desktop version?

Comment: @MillieSmith No I don't get any message like access denied or anything. The desktop version do the same... But don't worry I think I will remove everything and rewrite my own code, the previous intern didn't seem to be a programmer (no comment, no explicit method name, and so on...). Furthermore I will use JSON file instead of txt file. Thank you very much for your help